# Enter button and others write in other windows - Text editor

Tags: 19.10, text-editor

I opened multiple windows of text editor; when i press enter or when i press shift to insert a parenthesis, the output is not in the current window, but in another window. How can i fix it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct window focused before you press enter. Or it could be a touch pad that is inadvertently touched, registering a click in the wrong place. We can only guess, because you do not provide any specific information.

Comment: Hello @vanadium this is the first day i have this problem; the days before it was ok.

Comment: Still, there is no use in posting your problem if it remains so vague and not traceable by others. Anyway, perhaps others still know how to fix it based on the current info.